A question on the proof of the cardinality property of Stone space
David Marker asserts that if a Stone space over a countable subset in a countable language has the cardinality less than $2^{\aleph_0}$ then it has a finite or countable cardinality as Theorem 4.2.11, ii).
In the proof he claims that if $|[\phi]|>\aleph_0$, there is a formula $\psi$ such that $|[\phi\land\psi]|>\aleph_0$ and $|[\phi\land\neg\psi]|>\aleph_0$.
Suppose not. Let $p=\{\psi(\overline{v}):|[\phi\land\psi]|>\aleph_0\}$. He uses $[\phi]=\bigcup_{\psi\notin p}[\phi\land\psi]\cup\{p\}$ to present a contradiction.
So my question is: Why does the equation hold? Isn't it should be that $[\phi]=\bigcup_{\psi\notin p}[\phi\land\psi]\cup\bigcup_{\psi\in p}[\phi\land\psi]$ and the second union is much more a single $p$?
Edit: Now I see why. $[\phi]=[\phi]\cap S_n^{\mathcal{M}}(A)=[\phi]\cap(\bigcup_{\psi\notin p}[\psi]\cup (S_n^\mathcal{M}(A)\setminus(\bigcup_{\psi\notin p}[\psi])))$, where $S_n^\mathcal{M}(A)\setminus(\bigcup_{\psi\notin p}[\psi])=S_n^\mathcal{M}(A)\setminus[\bigvee_{\psi\notin p}\psi(\overline{v})]=[\neg\bigvee_{\psi\notin p}\psi(\overline{v})]=[\bigwedge_{\psi\notin p}\neg\psi(\overline{v})]$, and since $\psi\notin p$, let $\theta=\neg\psi$, by the assumption $\theta\in p$, now $[\bigwedge_{\psi\notin p}\neg\psi(\overline{v})]=[\bigwedge_{\theta\in p}\theta(\overline{v})]=\{p\}$ (formally).

If $q$ is a type containing $\phi$ and $q\neq p$, then there is some $\psi\in q$ such that $\psi\notin p$, so $q\in [\phi\land \psi]$.

Thanks, that's concise. And I wonder if my edit is right.

Your edit is the right idea, but since $\bigvee_{\psi\notin p} \psi$ is an infinite disjunction, it's not a first-order formula. So the notation $[\bigvee_{\psi\notin p} \psi]$ doesn't actually make sense.
